# How to call wcf methods from client proxy

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created one WCF service , which is working fine, now i want to consume it in a client application.
using SVCutil.exe i have generated proxy and aap.settings for that service and added  that to the client sln(console application)

But the problem is i am unable to access the wcf methods.

```
        using System.ServiceModel;

            namespace WCFClient
                    {
                     class Program
                     {
                     static void Main(string[] args)
                    {

                          Program p = new Program();
                         p. // not getting the wcf methods

                    }
                  }
                  }
```

what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how your service is called. When you created the service reference, you gave it a namespace name - in that namespace, there should be a class called (yourservicename)Client - instantiante one of those and get going.

You should find those files under the Service Reference - if you click on the "show all files" button in the Solution Explorer, you'll start seeing a ton of files under your service reference - one in particular should be `Reference.cs`. Those classes are defined in that file - you can check it out, it's a regular C# file.

**Update:** If you create your proxy using `svcutil.exe`, depending on your options used with `svcutil`, you should also get a .cs file that contains the classes needed.

```
svcutil http://yourserver/yourservice
```

would create a file called `(your WSDL name).cs` and an `output.config` in that directory where you run this command.

You can also specify a file name for the C# file:

```
svcutil http://yourserver/yourservice /out:MyService.cs
```

and then your file is called `MyService.cs`.

SvcUtil has a **ton** of options - can't explain them all to you, play around with them, read up on the MSDN docs for it.

Again, one of them will be called `(your service name)Client`. Include that *.cs file in your project, check the namespace, create an instance of the `.....Client` class and use it to call the WCF service.

**Example:**

- Grab info from URL

  ```
  svcutil http://www.ecubicle.net/iptocountry.asmx?wsdl /out:IP2CountryClient.cs
  ```
- Include the resulting `IP2CountryClient.cs` in your project; by default, the classes in that file are in no particular namespace, so they're globally visible
- Instantiate the client class `iptocountrySoapClient`

  ```
  iptocountrySoapClient  client = new iptocountrySoapClient();
  ```
- Call methods - e.g. this one here:

  ```
  string result = client.FindCountryAsString("82.82.82.82");
  ```

Comment: didnt get u ..my question is when i am creating proxy using svcutil.exe, inthat case how to access wcf methods.
If I do a add service ref things are workig fine, but what are the steps in case of svcutil.exe generated proxy